# How to resolve a stencil bundle error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigcommerce

When bundling a theme I've been working on stencil has been throwing an error that prevents it from completing the bundle. I'm really at a loss for what to do.

Here is the console log from the console log:

> E:\stencil>stencil bundle Validating theme... Running ESLint...
>
> E:\stencil\assets\js\theme\common\carousel.js   22:159  error  Parsing
>   error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag
>
> E:\stencil\assets\js\theme\common\product-details.js   300:15  warning
>   Function 'updateView' has a complexity of 13  complexity

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

> C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\stencil-bundle.js:255
>               throw err;
>                     ^ Error: Please fix the above Javascript errors.
>       at runLintTask (C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\bundle-validator.js:268:18)
>       at C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:718:13
>       at Immediate.iterate [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:262:13)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
>
> E:\stencil>

Comment: Have you updated Stencil CLI recently?

Comment: That install of the CLI is probably 2-3 weeks old I think? I'm not sure how to update it. And I'm afraid to reinstall it because it seems like that will override the custom work I've done on the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like ESLint doesn't like some of your JS. You can try making the rules in the .eslintrc file less strict, or even delete the file altogether as it is not necessary.

Once the file is removed try bundling again.

More info on eslint [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint).

Comment: Yes, I actually just realized I completely missed the the carousel.js file it mentions at the top.... I just fixed that and it was all good... bit embarrassed, but at least now its fixed.